# findOneAndUpdate property in array of objects

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to update a property in an array of objects - the find part already works. signedUp should be set to true.

Here's my method:

```
function lookupReferral(email) {
    return getConnection().then(db => db.collection('Referrals').findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            emails: {$elemMatch: {name: email}}
        }, 
        {
        $set: {
            emails: {$elemMatch: {signedUp: true}},
            updated: new Date()
        }
        }));
}
```

My idea in the $set clause is that I specify the particular object once again, and then the property that I'm setting, but it doesn't work. For further context, here's the record:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b60504420f8e626148494e4"
    },
    "accountCode": "auth0|5b4de18d8bed60110409ded5",
    "accountEmail": "example@gmail.com",
    "emails": [
        {
            "name": "azzz@zzz.dk",
            "signedUp": false
        },
        {
            "name": "ds@d.dk",
            "signedUp": false
        },
        {
            "name": "ds@d.dk",
            "signedUp": false
        },
        {
            "name": "ds@d.dk",
            "signedUp": false
        }
    ],
    "created": {
        "$date": "2018-07-31T12:04:20.625Z"
    },
    "updated": {
        "$date": "2018-07-31T12:04:20.625Z"
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [$(update)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator. For your case change update part to `{
        $set: {
            "emails.$.signedUp": true,
            updated: new Date()
        }`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Weird that the property has to be a string. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`$ positional`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)  operator to update an array element

```
db.collection('Referrals').findOneAndUpdate(
  { "emails": { "$elemMatch": { "name": email }}}, 
  { "$set": { "emails.$.signedUp": true, "emails.$.updated": new Date() }}
)
```